# Filter array of objects by multiple values

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I want to be able to create a new array of objects by filtering one by multiple search terms

Example:

```
  const arr = [
  {
      'city': 'Atlanta',
      'state': 'Georgia'
  },
  {
      'city': 'Chicago',
      'state': 'Illinois'
  },
  {
      'city': 'Miami',
      'state': 'Florida'
  }
]

const searchTerms = ['Georgia', 'Florida']
```

I would like to be able to filter it like this:

```
arr.filter(obj => obj['state'].includes(searchTerms))
```

I've found that entering one string with the .includes works, but not an array.  I'm open to different logic or even a third party library like lodash or something.  I would like to return a new array of objects with only the states that are in the searchterms array

Comment: you should search for state in searchTerms not the other way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call `searchTerms.includes` on `obj.state` and not the other way around. So it becomes:

```
let result = arr.filter(obj => searchTerms.includes(obj.state));
```

Which means *filter* out objects that have thier `state` property *included* in the array `searchItems`.

**Example:**

```js
const arr = [{'city': 'Atlanta', 'state': 'Georgia'}, {'city': 'Chicago', 'state': 'Illinois'}, {'city': 'Miami', 'state': 'Florida'}];

const searchTerms = ['Georgia', 'Florida'];

let result = arr.filter(obj => searchTerms.includes(obj.state));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  That worked and makes sense, must be too late and my brain not working right haha.  I'm gonna mark your answer when it let's me

Comment: You'e welcome! We all have those moments haha. Happy coding ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in a solution using [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/):

```js
const cities = [
  { 'city': 'Atlanta',
    'state': 'Georgia' },
    
  { 'city': 'Chicago',
    'state': 'Illinois' },
    
  { 'city': 'Miami',
    'state': 'Florida' } ];
    

const findCities = (search, cities) => {
  const predicate = R.flip(R.includes)(search);
  return R.filter(R.compose(predicate, R.prop('state')), cities);
};

console.log(
  findCities(['Georgia', 'Florida'], cities)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach you could take here is to utilize [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which would have consistent retrieval times:

```js
const arr = [ { 'city': 'Atlanta', 'state': 'Georgia' }, { 'city': 'Chicago', 'state': 'Illinois' }, { 'city': 'Miami', 'state': 'Florida' } ] 
const searchTerms = ['Georgia', 'Florida']

const searchMap = arr.reduce((r,c) => (r.set(c.state, c),r), new Map())

console.log(searchTerms.map(x => searchMap.get(x)))
```