# Is there any way how to find elements of array by multiple values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, javascript-objects

I have an array:

```
people = [
  {name: a, group: 1},
  {name: b, group: 2},
  {name: c, group: 3},
  {name: d, group: 2},
  {name: e, group: 3},
  {name: f, group: 1},
  {name: g, group: 1},
];
```

I need to find all people, who are in groups 2 and 3. 
Desired output:

```
filteredPeople = [
  {name: b, group: 2},
  {name: c, group: 3},
  {name: d, group: 2},
  {name: e, group: 3},
];
```

It might be other groups as well (groups using for search may change).

How I have to do that?

Comment: `filteredPeople = people.filter(i => [2,3].includes(i.group));`...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [filtering an array of objects based on another array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894352/filtering-an-array-of-objects-based-on-another-array-in-javascript) and [Filter array of objects by multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53576285) and  [Filter array of objects by multiple properties and values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330952)

Comment: @adiga oh, nice catch. Didn't find that.

Comment: might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/31831651/3514144

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter()` and `.includes()` methods to get the desired output:

```js
const data = [
  {name: 'a', group: 1}, {name: 'b', group: 2}, {name: 'c', group: 3},
  {name: 'd', group: 2}, {name: 'e', group: 3}, {name: 'f', group: 1},
  {name: 'g', group: 1}
];

const groups = [2, 3];

const result = data.filter(({ group }) => groups.includes(group));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

`filter` and `includes` do the job here. We use the rest operators (which gives us an array on which we can apply `includes`). So you can put any number of groups into the function call to be flexible when filtering.

```js
let people = [{name: "a",group:1},{name: "b",group:2},{name: "c",group:3},{name:"d",group:2},{name:"e",group:3},{name:"f",group:1},{name:"g",group:1}];

let filterGroups = (arr, ...groups) => arr.filter(o => groups.includes(o.group));

console.log(filterGroups(people, 2, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and the expression `2 === group || group === 3`

```js
const data = [{name: 'a', group: 1}, {name: 'b', group: 2}, {name: 'c', group: 3}, {name: 'd', group: 2}, {name: 'e', group: 3}, {name: 'f', group: 1}, {name: 'g', group: 1}];
const result = data.filter(({ group }) => group === 2 || group === 3);

console.log(result);
```